# mysql fetch assoc and print related table records

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to compose an email in php code.
I want to "print" out one of the records in first table (workgroups) in an table and underneath that record all the related records from my second table (workgroupmembers). After first record i want to go to next record in table workgrous and do same there intill all records have been printed.
The related field bewteen the two tables is WorkgroupDN.
Is i right approach to use an combination of  db_fetch_assoc and while?

Heres my tables:

```
Table ”workgroups”
CREATE TABLE `workgroups` (
`WorkgroupDN` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`WorkgroupDNID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`WorkgroupDNID`),
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Table ”workgroupsmembers”:

```
CREATE TABLE `workgroupmembers` (
`WorkgroupDN` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`HuntOrder` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UserDN` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`WorkgroupDN`, `HuntOrder`),
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This is what i got for now

```
global $cman;
$connection = $cman->byName("shoreware at 172.21.1.50");
$rs1 = $connection->query("SELECT WorkgroupDN, SUBSTRING(WorkgroupDN, 6, 8) AS 
extension, Description FROM workgroups INNER JOIN dn ON dn.DN = 
workgroups.WorkgroupDN WHERE BackupDN > '0' AND (SUBSTRING(WorkgroupDN, 1, 4)) 
= '".$prefix."' ORDER BY WorkgroupDN");
$data1 = db_fetch_assoc($rs1);
//Fill table with workgroups
while($data1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs1))
{
foreach($data1 as $field => $value){
$rs2 = $connection->query("SELECT WorkgroupDN, SUBSTRING(WorkgroupDN, 6, 8) AS 
extension, UserDN FROM workgroupmembers WHERE WorkgroupDN = 
'".$data1["WorkgroupDN"]."' ORDER BY UserDN");
$data2 = db_fetch_array($rs2);
$dnworkgroup.="
<tr><td width" . "=" . "160" . "align" . "=" . "center" . ">" . 
$data1["Description"] . "</td>" . "<td width" . "=" . "80" . "align" . "=" . 
"center" . ">" . $data1["WorkgroupDN"] . "</td>";
}
$dnworkgroupmembers.="
<tr><td width" . "=" . "160" . "align" . "=" . "center" . ">" . 
$field["UserDN"] . "</td>" . "<td width" . "=" . "80" . "align" . "=" . 
"center" . ">" . $field["UserDN"] . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: please reconstruct your question to state problem properly and in minimalistic way. it's too dificult to read.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.